# Javascript, access object.property

Tags: javascript, oop, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, backbone.js

In my code `this.options` returns object with `.all` object nested. Yet when I try to access it with `this.options['all']` or `this.options.all` I get `undefined`.

`console.log(this.options):`

```
Object
    all: Object
        cfg_autoresize: "true"
        cfg_autosave: "false"
        cfg_monthly_target: "monthly_target"
        cfg_statistics: "statistics"
        cfg_ticker: "ticker"
        cfg_yearly_target: "yearly_target"
    __proto__: Object
```

Could someone help me figure this out, never had this issue before. Thanks

### Edit:

#### content_script, simplified version

```
var Dashboard = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('body'),
    options: {},

    get_localStorage: function() {
        var _this = this;
        function handle_response(response) {_this.options.all = response.data;}
        chrome.extension.sendRequest({method: "allLocalStorage"}, handle_response);
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.get_localStorage();
        console.log(this.options); // above object
        console.log(this.options.all); //undefined
    }
});
```

#### background.html, taken from Google-chrome-extension docs and modified

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(request.method == "allLocalStorage") {

        var options = {};

        for (var i=0, l=localStorage.length; i<l; i++){
            var key = localStorage.key(i);
            var value = localStorage[key];
            options[key] = value;
        }

        sendResponse({data: options}); 

    } else {
        sendResponse({}); 
    }
});
```

Ideally I would like to have `this.options` have all options inside of it without `.all` but it would not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show us part of the js code (declaration and object access) that seems incorrect?

**EDIT:**

Ah i see... at the time you call get_localStorage(); the object might not being initialized due to the fact that the handle_response function will yet not get triggered before the sendRequest finishes.

you probably want to try something like the following:

```
get_localStorage: function(callback) {
    var _this = this;
    function handle_response(response) {
        _this.options.all = response.data;     
        callback(_this.options);
    }
    chrome.extension.sendRequest({method: "allLocalStorage"}, handle_response);
}

initialize: function() {
    this.get_localStorage(function(op) {
            console.log(op);
            console.log(op.all);
        }
    );
}
```